# What is an easy way to update PHP from 5.2.0 to 5.2.14 on Debian?

Tags: php, linux, debian

I want to update my version of PHP from 5.2.0 to 5.2.14 (or later, but I don't want to upgrade to 5.3 for compatibilty reasons).

Every guide I find to upgrade PHP is for updating to the last available version, but I dont't find a way to update to a specific version.

The easiest and quickest the solution, the best

Comment: maybe you need to send this question to serverfault

Comment: While you already said you don't want to, it is strongly recommended to upgrade to 5.3 though. The lifecycle of PHP 5.2 has officially ended end of 2010. If you are worried about compatibility issues, check out the migration guide: http://de2.php.net/migration53

Comment: Unfortunately, we have a lot of apps in there that will not work with 5.3. In the future we are planning on migrating, but for now we need to upgrade from 5.2.14 for very specific needs.

Comment: Fair enough. On yet another sidenote, the last stable 5.2 is [5.2.17 and fixes a a critical DDOS vulnerability](http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-01-06-1).

Comment: @eineki Don't you think SU or unix.SE are more suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. identify php-related packages you installed on the system; packages like `php5-cli`, `php5-cgi`, `libapache2-php5`
2. Pock around [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/) to see what is the latest available version of php 5.2.
3. Download these packages manually.
4. `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` at the directory you keep the debs
5. lock the installed version, prevent accidentally upgrade by `apt-get upgrade`.

There are might be ways to probe versions available using just `apt-get`, if anyone knows please share.

Comment: I dot´t know if you are being sarcastic, but if it was just slightly more detailed i think I could do it without problems. 
A few things that I am not sure about:
After step 1, do i have to uninstall those packages? 
Before step 4, do I need to uninstall the current version of php?

Comment: No, you don't have to uninstall the current ones or remove the ones you just installed. What the Debian packaging system would do is to upgrade them for you at Step 4.

Comment: I am not being sarcastic =P. I did those thing for one particular package once, and I am not sure if the dependency issue will hit you for massive 'subsystem' like php; that's what I meant 'not easy'.